# MongoDB - Query by 2dsphere returns zero results

Tags: java, mongodb

I wish to obtain a list of documents from a MongoDB collection by geospatial index. I have indexed the collection by 2dsphere

```
db.getCollection("Info").ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("location", "2dsphere"), "geospatial");
```

A document in the Info collection look like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52631572fe38203a7388ebb5"), "location" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  144.6682361,  -37.8978304 ] }
```

When I query the Info collection by the coordinates [  144.6682361,  -37.8978304 ], I am getting zero collections returned.

I am using JAVA API to perform the action. My JAVA code is below

```
DBCollection coll1=db.getCollection("Info");
BasicDBObject locQuery = new BasicDBObject();
locQuery.put("near", loc);
locQuery.append("maxDistance", 3000);           
locCursor =coll1.find(locQuery);
System.out.println("LOCCURSOR"+locCursor.size());
```

The locCursor.size() returns always 0. Not sure where I am missing. At the same time, I am not getting any errors. It just gives me 0 documents returned. Any ideas Mongo users? Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly pass the value of your co-ordinates into your query:

```
   double lat_lng_values[] = {144.6682361, -37.8978304};
    BasicDBObject geo = new BasicDBObject("$geometry", new BasicDBObject("type","Point").append("coordinates",lat_lng_values));
    BasicDBObject filter = new BasicDBObject("$near", geo);
    filter.put("$maxDistance", 3000);
    BasicDBObject locQuery = new BasicDBObject("location", filter);
    System.out.println(locQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I got the message "errmsg" : "exception: can't find any special indices: 2d (needs index), 2dsphere (needs index),  for: { loc: { $near: [ 144.6682361, -37.8978304 ], $maxDistance: 3000 } }". I believe this is because of indexing problem in the collection. But I have indexed the collection. Is the indexing statement wrong?

Comment: db.getCollection("Info").ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("location.coordinates", "2dsphere"), "geospatial"); -- Is this the correct index statement or db.getCollection("Messages").ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("location", "2dsphere"), "geospatial");??. I am not sure whether it should be location or location.coordinates?

Comment: Yes that may be the problem , try this way : DBObject index = BasicDBObjectBuilder.start("location", "2dsphere").get();
            DBCollection collection = new Mongo().getDB("DB_NAME").getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME");
            collection.ensureIndex(index);

Comment: Implemented the above code. But ran into the same issue again.  Even ran the stats in cmd prompt. It says the collection is indexed.    "count" : 5,
  "size" : 7984,
  "avgObjSize" : 1596.8,
  "storageSize" : 516096,
  "numExtents" : 3,
  "nindexes" : 3,
  "lastExtentSize" : 393216,
  "paddingFactor" : 1,
  "systemFlags" : 1,
  "userFlags" : 0,
  "totalIndexSize" : 24528,
  "indexSizes" : {
          "_id_" : 8176,
          "geospatial" : 8176
  },
  "ok" : 1

Comment: instead of 'location',i had written 'loc' in the answer, hence the edit, now i think it must work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39587/discussion-between-timothy-rajan-and-jhanvi)

Comment: I have implemented your solution. Yes. That got resolved. But getting another issue now  "errmsg" : "exception: can't parse query (2dsphere): { $near: [ 144.6682361, -37.8978304 ], $maxDistance: 3000 }"

Comment: This command is working in cmd prompt. db.Info.find( { location : { $near :{ $geometry :{ type : "Point" ,coordinates: [ 144.6682361, -37.8978304 ] } },$maxDistance : 500} } ) Do we need to add $geometry in the DBObject?

Comment: Thats not needed as per this url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458457/near-query-through-java. Moreover I am not sure how to add it. Since I cant deduce the value of $geometry

Comment: no, its needed, refer the docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-a-2dsphere-index/

Comment: Not able to find how to add $geometry to the DBObject. Can you help me pls.

Comment: @TimothyRajan have edited the answer, addeded DBObject in geometry

Comment: Thanks. Stumped into another issue. "errmsg" : "exception: $near requires geojson point, given { type: \"Point\" }"

Comment: But { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  144.6682361,  -37.8978304 ] } is a valid geojson input. Not sure why this error is thrown at this point.

Comment: embedd the entire geo object into 1 and try again, as changed in edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now  I am able to get the correct result. Thanks once again